# ChartJS tooltip label for pie cart being cut

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to add tooltip in my chart, however some of them the label are being cut.

[image: The label is cut]

Hier is my code

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: data,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: title,
                fontSize: 36
            },
            tooltips: {
                bodyFontSize: 22,
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var number = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        var sum = data.datasets[0].data.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
                        var percentage = getPercent(number, sum);
                        return label + " " + Math.round(percentage) + " %";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me to make the label rendered properly? Many thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your tooltip is going off the edge of your canvas, have a look at [this jsfiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/wqt2gmab/2/). Or see sample code at the end.

Or, without seeing the full code, I might assume that your 2014 chart is overlapping the 2015 chart.  Maybe fixed with a z-index in CSS, but then the opposite effect with the other chart may happen?

Same code from jsfiddle:

```
<div style='width: 300px;'>
    <canvas id='chart'></canvas>
</div>

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["I am a really really really really really really  really really really really really reallyreally really really really really really long label so long I might go off the chart"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [5],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
            display: false,
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
});
```